# Print all the places when a certain sentence appear

Tags: terminal, grep, command

I'm using the terminal and want to trace all the appearances of a certain sentence. 
I have navigated to the folder and written the following command:

```
grep 'myWord' > findWord.txt
```

The file is empty and the I need to press ^C in order to exit the command.

I would also like to know in what files this word exists.

Answer (score 0):

You failed to give the input file. Anything after the output redirection operator is considered as output file. So Your grep syntax would be,

```
grep 'myWord' input-file > output-file
```

Comment: And if I want to search the entire folder?

Comment: `grep 'myword' *.txt`